# Access Kubernetes service from vm in same GCE project

Tags: service, connection, kubernetes

The pods inside a Google Container Engine cluster can be reached directly from any vm in the same GCE project. However the service's internal ip is not reachable, I guess because it's a virtual ip and not meant to be accessible externally.

What's the best way to make the service accessible without using type loadbalancer and exposing the service publicly? Do I need to use the ingress object and an nginx / haproxy ingress controller? Or is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you mean by "make the service accessible" and "without exposing the service publicly". You mean you want to be able to reach your service from GCE, outside a GKE cluster, but not from outside GCP?

If that's what you mean, please take a look at `externalIP` field in the serviceSpec - http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#external-ips. You can assign an external IP address to your service and then install the right firewall rules.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. Accessible from everything in the GCE project outside the GKE cluster, but not from outside GCP. 

I've looked at the externalIP approach before, but it seems I would need one of the GKE nodes external ips, which are ephemeral. Not sure if I can easily use static ips for those nodes as Google does the cluster bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late, but I am also facing the same issue and I have a partial solution.

I didn't want my service to be exposed publicly, so no ingress or node-port service for me.

In GKE the Kubernetes service virtual IP range is only accessible within the cluster by default.

But you can make it accessible outside cluster by creating a GCE route that allows you to forwards kubernetes service's virtual IP range to any one of the kubernetes nodes, like below.

`gcloud compute routes create --destination-range 10.x.x.x/20 --next-hop-instance kube-node-0`

This is obviously a hack as this will fail in cases, the node where's all service traffic is going, fails for any reason (cluster upgrade/kube version upgrade etc.).

The solution, seems to me, is to have a external node that autodiscovers kubernetes nodes and loadbalances the external service traffic, though I haven't gotten it to work yet.

I found this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2bhV81MfKQ) to be extremely useful in understanding kubernetes and GKE networking.

Answer (score 0):

[Internal load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing) seems to be the way to go